# Every other odd number array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, math

I have a function titled "odd" which returns an array of only odd numbers in an inclusive range. It is given below.

```
func odd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    let list = [Int](stride(from: start, to: end+1, by: 2))
    return list
}
```

I am trying to make a function that returns an array of every other odd number, instead of every odd number. This function should be inclusive, too.

```
func alternatingOdd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    var list = odd(from: start, to: end)
    // ... black magic trickery turns removes every other number from list... 
    return list
}
```

Calling this function like so: `alternatingOdd(from: 1, to: 25)` would return an array of `[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25]`.

In essence, I am asking: how would I cleanly delete every other element from an array?

**EDIT**: the "odd" function does not always return an odd array based on user input. It only returns an array of values incremented by 2 through a range.

How do I bulletproof it and make sure it always returns odd numbers only? That is, each element in the array must not be evenly divisible by two.

Comment: what do you mean  "returns an array of every other odd number"

Comment: Unrelated but instead `to: end+1` you can write `through: end`

Comment: You may just use code of `odd` function, and replace `by: 2` with `by: 4`.

Comment: @MohmmadS Perhaps it is easier to show an example. An array of every odd number from 1 to 9 would be `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, but an array of every other odd number from 1 to 9 would be `[1, 5, 9]`, where 3 and 7 are deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than creating the arrays with `stride` `filter` the stuff with the modulo operator

The `odd` function keeps the odd numbers

```
func odd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    return (start...end).filter{$0 % 2 == 1}
}
```

or with a more modern API

```
func odd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    return (start...end).filter{$0.isMultiple(of: 2) == false}
}
```

The `alternatingOdd` function uses `compactMap` to filter the indices

```
func alternatingOdd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    let list = odd(from: start, to: end)
    return list.indices.compactMap{$0 % 2 == 0 ? list[$0] : nil }
}
```

Comment: are you sure index(of: runs in constant time?... it isn't... we can easily find an O(n) solution for the alternatingOdd function

Comment: higher order functions are fancy but we can do it in O(n) by trading off some more space and using an old style for loop. with index%2 condition.

Comment: @Naresh I updated the answer with a more efficient solution

Comment: wow that's awesome... its a lot better than the previous one... how about changing the last line to "return stride(from: 0, through: list.count-1, by: 2).map{list[$0]}" it takes 1/3rd time of the current solution :)

Answer (score 4):

You can efficiently strip every second element of an (arbitrary) array by mapping every second array *index* to the corresponding array *element:*

```
func everySecond<T>(of array: [T]) -> [T] {
    return stride(from: array.startIndex, to: array.endIndex, by: 2).map { array[$0] }
}
```

Examples:

```
print(everySecond(of: [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 6])) // [1, 2, 4]
print(everySecond(of: ["H", "E", "L", "L", "O"])) // ["H", "L", "O"]
```

Now you can use that in your function as

```
func alternatingOdd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    let odds = odd(from: start, to: end)
    return everySecond(of: odds)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get every other odd number in one go, and more efficiently, this way :

```
func alternatingOdd(from start: Int, to end: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard start >= 0  else { return [] }

    let oddStart = (start % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + start

    return Array(stride(from: oddStart, through: end, by: 4))
}

alternatingOdd(from: 1, to: 25)  //[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25]
```

You can even change how many odd numbers you'd be dropping :

```
func alternatingOdd(from start: Int, to end: Int, every step: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard start >= 0, step > 0  else { return [] }

    let oddStart = (start % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + start

    return Array(stride(from: oddStart, through: end, by: 2 * step))
}

alternatingOdd(from: 1, to: 25, every: 2)  //[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25]
alternatingOdd(from: 1, to: 25, every: 3)  //[1, 7, 13, 19, 25]
```

For ranges that start with a negative number, you could return only the positive odd numbers, if any, this way:

```
func alternatingOdd(from start: Int, to end: Int, every step: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard step > 0  else { return [] }

    let oddStart = max((start % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + start, 1)

    return Array(stride(from: oddStart, through: end, by: 2 * step))
}

alternatingOdd(from: -3, to: 10, every: 2)  //[1, 5, 9]
alternatingOdd(from: -3, to: 25, every: 4)  //[1, 9, 17, 25]
```

Comment: Why the special treatment of negative boundaries? I would expect `alternatingOdd(from: -7, to: 3)` to simply return `[-7, -3, 1]`

Comment: @MartinR I didn't feel that negative numbers would be wanted here. But you're right, according to their definition, negative numbers could be included.